# Update view when item's property of ObservableCollection is changed

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, winui

I have xaml code

```
<ListView x:Name="ListObject"
              ItemsSource="{x:Bind ObjectList}">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness}">
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate></ListView>
```

Code-behind:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<Item> ObjectList = new();
public class Item
{
        public Thickness BorderThickness { get; set; }
}
```

when I do `ObjectList.Add(new Item(){BorderThickness = new(10)})`, It will create a grid with borderthickness = 10 as expected. Now I want to change the border thickness of item to 100, I do  `ObjectList[0].BorderThickness =new(100)`, but it doesn't work, the view isn't updated.

So, my question is how do I change the item's border thickness in ObservableCollection and update to the view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Item` class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and raise the event when the value of Thickness changes.  For example:

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Thickness borderThickness;

    public Thickness BorderThickness
    {
        get { return borderThickness; }
        set
        {
            if (borderThickness!= value)
            {
                borderThickness= value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BorderThickness));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Then, make sure to set the mode of the binding to OneWay, because by default it is OneTime.